Ensuring Accurate Extrinsic IDs for Asset Transfers on AssetHub
I'm submitting asset transfer transactions on AssetHub using the submit and watch method. Immediately after submitting a transaction, I retrieve the block hash in which it was supposedly included. I then use this hash to fetch the block and check the transaction index, block number, etc. Using the block number and index, I'm able to create a unique identifier (extrinsic ID) for the transaction which is what i need to do.
This process works most of the time, but I've noticed that occasionally the transaction isn't included in the block returned by the submit function, but rather in the subsequent block. Is this even possible ?
The system is developed in Go, and I'm using the Centrifuge Go Substrate RPC client. I'm wondering if this behaviour is something inherent to the chain, or if it's an issue with the library.
I need a unique identifier immediately after submitting the transaction, but if the block number changes, I can't predict t
he extrinsic ID. Additionally, transaction hashes aren't unique, so I can't rely on them.
Am I missing something, how i can reliably find the extrinsic id right after publishing the transaction ?


Am I missing something, how i can reliably find the extrinsic id right after publishing the transaction ?

The Extrinsic Id is only fixed once the block is finalized in which it is included. So it is not really possible to get that id immediately after submitting.
The block that was returned by the API can still be removed again from the chain through a re-org. This is possibly what happens sometimes in your case.
These things can happen - until the block is finalized.
